# How and where in Evernote ENEX files is information stored about which thumbnail image to display?

Tags: xml, dtd, evernote

I am looking through the Evernote ENEX document type definition (DTD) document at http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd to determine how the ENEX file stores information about which thumbnail image to display (in the various views on the Windows/Mac/web and mobile clients that show thumbnails) but I am not seeing it.  I also created a simple Evernote note with a single image for which I can see the thumbnail in the clients but I don't see how this is stored in the associated ENEX file.

Or...  is this data not stored, but rather determined at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no explicit flag indicating that a given resource (image) should be used as the thumbnail. Each client makes its own decision at runtime depending on how it will be rendering the note.